# dart stdin unicode wrong?

Tags: dart, unicode, stdin, cjk

```dart
// os: win10

import "dart:io";

void main() {
  stdin.listen(print);
}
```

it is correct when I input pure ascii:

```
> abc
> [97, 98, 99]
```

is **wrong** when I input some unicode:

```
> a你好b
> [97, 0, 0, 98]
```

How can I get the correct string?

Comment: I am not sure what the answer is here, but it works for me as you would expect. 
`abcde fg`
`[97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 32, 102, 103, 10]`
`a你好b`
`[97, 228, 189, 160, 229, 165, 189, 98, 10]`
`你`
`[228, 189, 160, 10]`
`안녕하세요`
`[27, 91, 49, 59, 50, 68, 236, 149, 136, 235, 133, 149, 237, 149, 152, 236, 132, 184, 236, 154, 148, 27, 91, 68, 27, 91, 67, 10]`
I am running dart version 2.10.2 on windows. Sorry all the lines are squished together for comments.

Comment: @Stephen thank you very much. My dart version is 2.10.4(stable). I download dart 2.10.2(stable) and run again, and I get the wrong answer again. Maybe it is wrong with my computer...thank you again.

Comment: Check the entire chain: encoding/character set terminal/console where you enter the text, encoding associated with *stdin*, encoding associated with *stdout*, encoding/characters set of terminal where text is output (if different from input).

Comment: @Codo thank you for you reply, I have tried utf-8 and gbk in my terminal, I will try to reinstall dart/flutter, thank you.

Comment: Changing the encoding in the terminal might not be sufficient. The terminal might be okay but the dart program might assume that you are using ANSI encoding.

Comment: If you are on Windows, check [`systemEncoding`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.3/dart-io/systemEncoding-constant.html), which is derived from the active code page, a constant pain on all Windows systems.